# How to read multi byte serial data?

Tags: python, uart

I am having some problems reading data from a UART slave device on my rapberry pi. 
The manual for the device is this: https://app.box.com/shared/static/4l8fiyowu4agg26lc7fu234edci1n8no.pdf

On page 12 it indicates that the data that is sent from the slave device is in Little Endian format. This is the first time I work with python and I'm not having good luck trying find a way to interpret that kind of data.

If I send a byte array of [7,75,0,76] (page 17, reading power average), the message i get back is: b'K\x1c\x00W'

This is my code so far:

```
import serial
import time
import struct


ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyS0',
                    baudrate=19200,
                    parity='N',
                    bytesize=8,
                    stopbits=1,
                    timeout = 1) 


print ("Starting up")
print(ser.name)
connected = False
commandToSend = '[7,75,0,76]' # get the distance in mm

while True:
    print ("Writing: ",  commandToSend)
    values = bytearray([7,75,0,76])
    ser.write(values)

    while True:
        try:
            print ("Attempt to Read")
            ans = ser.read(4)
            print ("Reading: ", ans)
            time.sleep(5)
            break
        except:
            pass
    print ("Restart--------------------------------")
    ser.flush() #flush the buffer
```

for any other command that has a byte size of 1, i have no problems at all. At least i know that the checksum and the messages are sent correctly, the only problem is reading the ones that exceed 1.

thanks for helping me out

Comment: The [struct](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) module is a good way to read/write serial data. A format string describes the byte level data and `struct.unpack` reads it into python.

Comment: *"data that is sent from the slave device is in Little Endian format"* -- That only applies to multi-byte quantiies, e.g. integers.  Simplest way to deal with these 4-byte messages is to receive the data in a byte array.  Then calculate the 2-byte integer value as `256 * HiValue + LoValue`, where HiValue and LoValue are unsigned byte elements of the array.